# Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32) using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error when trying to run a trigger that updated a transaction date to today's date.

```
Create Trigger _trgUpdateDate
on [dbo].[_etblPOPRequisitions]
After Update
AS
    Update [dbo].[_etblPOPRequisitions]
    set dRequisitionDate = GETDATE()
    where idPOPRequisitions 
    in 
    (select distinct idPOPRequisitions from inserted)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Technically, the system needs to update the date to today's date regardless of what date you capture in the application's front end.

Comment: you are updating the same table that got updated?  if all you want to do is modify the incoming record with a date value, then no UPDATE is needed in the trigger

Comment: Why don't you just create a default on dRequisitionDate as getdate()?

Comment: I would not use a trigger for this.  Does the update occur via a stored procedure or T SQL sprinkled in the application?

Comment: It's good practice to put the following boilerplate in every trigger: `SET NOCOUNT ON; IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;` The former to prevent triggers from polluting affected row counts; the latter to prevent triggers from triggering triggers. (Triggers will not, by default, trigger *themselves*, but that's the only protection you get -- with two triggers, infinite recursion is still easy, and you typically don't know if other people have defined triggers already.)

Comment: You update the table `_etblPOPRequisitions` inside the trigger for the table, so it is in infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that nested triggers is disabled. How to disable and enable nested triggers, can be found in the microsoft documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option

When nested triggers are enabled, and you have multiple triggers, than it can work as a loop.

Comment: By default, an `AFTER` trigger will not call itself unless the `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` option on the database is set, so you need at least two triggers to get an infinite recursion. That's still extremely easy to do accidentally, though. `nested triggers` is a server-wide option, which is both a benefit and a drawback (pro: you can get rid of all nested triggers at once, con: databases that are prepared to handle the nesting might need this functionality).